# C# Forms drawing Image with color

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to draw an image in C# Forms, but I'm missing the color parameter like SpriteBatch.Draw in XNA, so I can draw white images as red and green images with a tint of red and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: There aren't any built in methods to do this for you since we are talking about basic winforms. You need to do it manually by manipulating the bitmap or finding a third party library to do it for you. http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale

Comment: Okay, then how do I do it using a Color object and a Color Matrix? there's only grayscaling in this example

Comment: Instead of *removing* color like the example, look for a color or range of colors you want to swap and then replace it with the color(s) you need.

Comment: Okay, I found it out. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.